# Why it was so important for Bumi that Momo was with Aang while he was preparing for the final battle?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

In [Sozin's Comet, Part 2: The Old Masters](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Sozin%27s_Comet,_Part_2%3a_The_Old_Masters) (the 2th part of the 4 parts finale), [Bumi](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Bumi) (the wild-eyed, eccentric king and earthbending master) made this remark :

> Bumi then notices that their group is missing someone, and says "Someone's missing.... where's Momo?" Sokka answers he is gone and that he is with Aang. Bumi says, without a single worry, that it is okay because they have each other.

After that, I expected him to play a part in the outcome, but I didn't noticed any action of Momo that made his presence critical. did I miss something or it was just crazy talk from the old men?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bumi is a crazy old man, so it may just be crazy talk, but...

Momo and Aang have a pretty deep connection, just like Aang and Appa. It's this connection that possibly keeps him grounded when he speaks to the past Avatars on the Lion Turtles back and learns about what they would do. Rather than taking the advice of the past Avatars, he chooses to suck the Fire lords bending powers out of him. I'm sure at some point on the island he converses with Momo either about this or the general theme of him staying grounded in the real world.

I think in general Bumi *knows* Aang is a resourceful and very powerful kid. But he has a propensity to get overly involved and take things too seriously, which is why he needs Momo.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to dismiss this exchange and chalk it up to Bumi's eccentricity. However, he's always shown that his decisions no matter how out the ordinary they seem at the time, are well thought out.

So what does he mean by the statement? First off he mentions that Momo is missing (not Aang) meaning he expects Aang to be separated from the group in anticipation of his confrontation with Osai.

Momo and Aang are kindred spirits. In the first act, Aang says to Momo that they were the last survivors of the Air Temple. It is Momo and Appa (along with his love for Kitara) that keeps Aang "grounded". Bumi knows this and states that as long as they have each other, they'll be okay.